# How do we show that the following language is undecidable

Tags: computation-theory, computer-science-theory

How do we show that the following language is undecidable.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/In68J.png)

I am not really sure where to start for the proof. Probably using one of A<sub>TM</sub>, HALT<sub>TM</sub>, or E<sub>TM</sub> to help because they are all undecidable. I can do those undecidability proofs so just using them with the assumption of being undecidable in the proof is fine.

Comment: Better on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ perhaps

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is probably reduction from the halting problem.

That is, you need to describe a simple transformation (think algorithm) `X` from an arbitrary TM, call it `A`, into a new machine `M`, s.t. if you *did* have a way of determining whether `M` ever writes a given string `a` on the tape, it would tell you whether `A` halts.

Another way of putting this is that `X` must guarantee that `A` halts if and only if M ever writes `a` on the tape. You get to pick any `a` you like.

Since with X in hand you have a solution to the general halting problem - which is known undecidable - the given language is also undecidable.